# my if condition is not working inside my switch case, code rather. move directly to the default statement even when the conditions inside if is true

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

// this is my form that take first name and last name
// can someone help me out

```
    <form action="signup_verification.php" method='POST'>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <label for="first_name">First name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name='first_name'>
                </div>
                <div class="form-box">
                    <label for="last_name">Last name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name='last_name'>
                </div>
    </form>
```

// this is my php code to verify if all conditions are set properly.

```
    <?php
        $errormsg='';
        foreach ($_POST as $post){
            $post = htmlspecialchars($post);
        }
        switch($post):
            case 'first_name':
                if(empty($_POST['first_name'])){
                    $errormsg='First name is required';
                    return header('location:http://localhost:8888/LoginSite/signup.php?errormsg='.$errormsg);
                    break;
                }
            break;
            case 'last_name':
                if(empty($_POST['last_name'])){
                    $errormsg='Last name is required';
                    return header('location:http://localhost:8888/LoginSite/signup.php?errormsg='.$errormsg);
                    break;
                }
            break;
    
            default: 
                echo'yes';
        endswitch;    
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you checking the field name or the field value?

Comment: What's that `switch` for? You could just "extract" the `if` conditions inside and take the `switch` away. I don't see any benefit in using `switch` here.

Comment: Your `foreach` is overwriting `$post` on every iteration - and you do nothing with the result!! - leaving you with only one value after the `foreach`. You're also only checking for the values of the post fields, not their names (print `$post` inside the `foreach` to debug).

Answer (score 1):

Reference the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), `$_POST` is an associative array, where the keys are the name of the HTML input elements, they are `first_name` and `last_name`; whereas the array's values are the input values in the HTML form. Therefore we can have this `foreach`:

```php
$errmsg = '';
foreach ($_POST as $key = $value) {
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    if (empty($value) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'first_name':
                 $errmsg = 'First name is required';
                 break;
            case 'last_name':
                 $errmsg = 'Last name is required';
                 break;
        }
        return header('location:http://localhost:8888/LoginSite/signup.php?errormsg='.$errormsg);
    }
}

echo 'yes';
```